# Aggregate Key, Value pairs in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, aggregate

I have a spark dataset with the following format:

```
c1    c2
--------
a     d
a     c
a     d
b     e
b     d
```

What I would like to do is get something like the following (x is sorted by count).

```
c1           x
-----------------------
a     [(d, 2), (c, 1)]
b     [(e, 1), (d, 1)]
```

I am able to get

```
c1     c2     count
----------------------
a      d      2
a      c      1
b      e      1
b      d      1
```

via a `df.groupBy(c1, c2).count()`, but no idea how to proceed from there.
I've also explored `df.groupBy(c1).agg(collect_list(c2))`, which gives me

```
a     [d,c,d]
b     [e,d]
```

which is not quite what I need, and from my understanding would have issues scaling to large datasets.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a draft as I had no time to test it but you should get an idea:

```java
//you initial data
Dataset initialData;
//map values to has set with counts initiali 1 for every element
initialData.map((key, value) => {
  Map<Character, Integer> res = new HashMap<>();
  res.add(value, 1);
  Tuple2<Character, Map<Character, Integer>> tuple = new Tuple2<>(key, res);
  return tuple;
//count elements for given key
}).reduceByKey((map1, map2) => {
  final Map<Character, Integer> res = new HashMap<>();
  res.putAll(map1);
  map2.foreach((key, value) => {
    if (res.contains(key))
      res.put(key, map2(key) + value);
    else
      res.put(key, map2(key));
  }
  return res;
//sort values by count
}.map((key, value) => {
  List<SetEntry<Character, Integer>> entryList = new ArrayList<>(value.entrySet());

  collection.sort(entryList, (entry1, entry2) => 
    entry1.getValue() < entry2.getValue());
  return new Tuple2<>(key, entryList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Was able to get the sense of what you were saying and take it from there. An important thing to note is that you can't return a tuple with an List of an entryset, as it is not serializable. Just modified that to collect as a HashMap, and a couple of other changes.

Comment: @diabolicalangle I'm glad I could help. Feel free to edit the answer according to your changes if you gonna have a change.